# Pygsheets, can't find client_secret.json

Tags: python-2.7, google-sheets-api

I try to use pygsheet to interact with googlesheet, I have downloaded that `client_secret.json` file and saved it in the same folder as where my py file is, but I kept getting the following error message!!

I promise I have saved that Jason file in multiple places (where the py file is, where the pysheet is installed.).

Please help me!!!

```
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
[evaluate untitled-2.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 3, in <module>
    pass
  File "c:\Users\mimi\.windows-build-tools\python27\Lib\site-packages\pygsheets\client.py", line 549, in authorize
    outh_nonlocal=outh_nonlocal)
  File "c:\Users\mimi\.windows-build-tools\python27\Lib\site-packages\pygsheets\client.py", line 505, in get_outh_credentials
```

> raise IOError(2, "Client secret file does not exist.",
>   client_secret_file) IOError: [Errno 2] Client secret file does not
>   exist.: 'client_secret.json'

Also, I checked the client.py file and noted the current setting is

```
def authorize(outh_file='client_secret.json', outh_creds_store=None, outh_nonlocal=False, service_file=None, credentials=None, **client_kwargs):
```

**EDIT** :

I realized I should put that file in Scripts folder. Fixed!.

But now I have the following error.

```
`[evaluate untitled-2.py] Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 6, in <module> File "c:\Users\mimi\.windows-build-tools\python27\Lib\site-packag‌​es\pygsheets\client.‌​py", line 173, in open raise SpreadsheetNotFound(title) pygsheets.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound:`
```

I used the code `sh = gc.open('xxx')` , and I think I used the right google spreadsheet name!!

Comment: I realized I should put that file in Scripts folder. Fixed!. But now I have the following error.    
[evaluate untitled-2.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "c:\Users\mimi\.windows-build-tools\python27\Lib\site-packages\pygsheets\client.py", line 173, in open
    raise SpreadsheetNotFound(title)
pygsheets.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound:           I used the code sh = gc.open('xxx') , and I think I used the right google spreadsheet name!!

Comment: Can you show the codes you are using?

Comment: When you say Scripts folder, you mean specific what folder? I got the same error and stuck.